# PHP not accessing database on server but accessing database on localhost

Tags: cpanel

I've been trying to rectify this for days but it's leading me no where
It works well on localhost, but no accessing database on the remote server
I've spent a lot of hours on this

Here is the code:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect ('scholars.lextoXXX.com', 'scholars_root', '', 'scholars_crud') OR
trigger_error("Could not connect to the database!\n<br />MySQL Error: " .
mysqli_connect_error());
```

Is there a configuration for that on the server.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show the error??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you enable remote mysql on your mysql server? Please try to enable it and allow port 3306 in server firewall so that you can access mysql.